# SQL Order By Specific String in a Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I was recently tasked to put a column in order base on a specific string. Bellow is the screenshot of my table:

[image]

How can I sort the picture column in the following order:

```
2017/June/06/169799_1_kYFJf.jpg
2017/February/18/169799_2_rkJ2d.jpg
2017/January/12/169799_3_23wKj.jpg
2017/March/18/169799_4_iMbw7.jpg
2017/May/18/169799_5_HwDBf.jpg
```

I tried `ORDER BY picture DESC` but it didn't work.

Unfortunately I am not allowed to add a new column, like maybe column "sort", which will define the sort number of the image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

**Example data:**

```
select * from test;
+--------+----------------------------------------+
| pid    | picture                                |
+--------+----------------------------------------+
| 169799 | 2017/March/18/169799_4_iMbw7.jpg       |
| 169799 | 2017/February/18/169799_2_jadsflkjasdf |
| 169799 | 2017/June/06/169799_1_jasfd;ads        |
| 169799 | 2017/May/18/169799_5_jasfd;ads         |
| 169799 | 2017/June/12/169799_10_jasfd;ads       |
| 169799 | 2017/January/12/169799_3_iMbw7.jpg     |
+--------+----------------------------------------+
```

## Sort by date

```
select * from test order by str_to_date(substring_index(picture,'/',3), '%Y/%M/%d') desc;
+--------+----------------------------------------+
| pid    | picture                                |
+--------+----------------------------------------+
| 169799 | 2017/June/12/169799_10_jasfd;ads       |
| 169799 | 2017/June/06/169799_1_jasfd;ads        |
| 169799 | 2017/May/18/169799_5_jasfd;ads         |
| 169799 | 2017/March/18/169799_4_iMbw7.jpg       |
| 169799 | 2017/February/18/169799_2_jadsflkjasdf |
| 169799 | 2017/January/12/169799_3_iMbw7.jpg     |
+--------+----------------------------------------+
```

**Explanation:**

- `substring_index(picture,'/',3)` will split text by `/` and output the first 3 item
- `str_to_date(..., '%Y/%M/%d')` converts the result to a date based on the given format. `%M` is month name

**EDIT**

## Sort by number

```
select * from test
order by cast(
  substring_index(substring_index(picture, '_', 2), '_', -1)
  as unsigned
);
+--------+----------------------------------------+
| pid    | picture                                |
+--------+----------------------------------------+
| 169799 | 2017/June/06/169799_1_jasfd;ads        |
| 169799 | 2017/February/18/169799_2_jadsflkjasdf |
| 169799 | 2017/January/12/169799_3_iMbw7.jpg     |
| 169799 | 2017/March/18/169799_4_iMbw7.jpg       |
| 169799 | 2017/May/18/169799_5_jasfd;ads         |
| 169799 | 2017/June/12/169799_10_jasfd;ads       |
+--------+----------------------------------------+
```

**Explanation:**

- `substring_index(picture, '_', 2)` will split text by `_` and output the first 2 item
- `substring_index(..., '_', -1)` picks the last item, which is the number

**References:**

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick answer. I need it ordered by the numbers after the string "169799_", it should be: 169799_1, 169799_2, 169799_3, 169799_4, 169799_5. Any idea how I achieve this?

Comment: Ah, okay. Sure, let me try something.

Comment: Do you want to order by date in the picture or do you want to order by the number?

Comment: just the numbers

Comment: `select * from test order by substring_index(substring_index(picture, '_', 2), '_', -1);` should do it

Comment: EDIT included now. Give it a try

Comment: Cool it works, but i'm a little curious on the use of 2 substring_index, can cause slow performance?

Comment: On your database table, do `explain ...query...` and see if it is hitting the right indexes. Performance is something you will have to test out with the queries you write. If you have thousands/millions of record, it might be most suitable to add a new column; but I understand you aren't at a liberty to do so. Test it out with `explain`

Comment: I tried more than 10 items to sort, it's showing:169799_1, 
169799_10, 
169799_11, 
169799_12, 
169799_2, 
169799_3, 
169799_4, 
169799_5, 
169799_6, 
169799_7, 
169799_8, 
169799_9

Comment: Casting! I'll update the answer. `order by cast(substring_index(substring_index(picture, '_', 2), '_', -1) as unsigned)` will help in correctly sorting as numbers

Comment: Thanks for patiently working on this. Yes the casting works!, please do update answer so I can mark as correct answer.

Answer (score 3):

try this one:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(picture, LOCATE(pid, picture) + LENGTH(pid) + 1, 1) DESC
```

Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7a334c/3

It's a combination of various string functions readily available for MySQL

For the SUBSTRING function, it takes the string you want to get a substring of, the starting position, and the length of substring you wish to extract..

So lets break down the three parameters we used for the SUBSTRING function

1.) picture - the column that we need to extract the numbers from

2.) LOCATE(pid, picture) + LENGTH(pid) + 1 - we are locating the string containing the pid substring from the picture column, then adding the length of the pid itself so we get the "underscore" character, then adding 1 again to get the "number" for sorting.. this will return the position of the number after the pid and "underscore" character

3.) 1 - This represents the length that you need to "cut" or "extract" from the string, this will pose a problem if you have 2 digits to extract... but for now, we can work with this..

http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-substring-function.php

Comment: Your code works!, but it looks a little strange to me. Could you explain it a little bit please? especially this part of your code: SUBSTRING(picture, LOCATE(pid, picture) + LENGTH(pid) + 1, 1); sorry newby here

Comment: I updated the answer, will update more later.. but this will hopefully give you a brief insight to what I did

Comment: Hi, you're correct, i've tried more than 10 items and the order appeared incorrect. Can you update the query to sort more than 10 items please?

Answer (score 2):

Hi so you can do a case statement but I couldn't figure out the logic you wanted it to order by ? Is it the 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 in the middle in the filename ? You can also use a regular expression to just look at those numbers and order by that. I don't know regular expressions off the top of my head though. What I gave you will work but its not the best answer as it's a lot of overhead in the query with poor performance.

```
order by
(Case when picture like '%_1_%' then '1'
when picture like '%_2_%' then '2'
when picture like '%_3_%' then '3'
when picture like '%_4_%' then '4'
when picture like '%_5_%' then '5' else '0' end)
```

Just keep adding the order you want it to sort by depending on how many numbers that go but again this might be a lot of overhead in a query and take a bit of time. Not sure how faster a regular expression can be to parse out just the number after the underscores to sort by. So performance might be an issue with my answer.

Comment: Yes I do feel like this might not be suitable query for our application as we are currently focusing on optimizing query speed. But thanks so much for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

In virtually all dialects of SQL, you could do the following:

```
order by 
    to_number(
        substr(
            picture,
            instr(picture,'_',1,1)+1,
            instr(picture,'_',1,2) - instr(picture,'_',1,1) -1))
```

Some dialects of SQL (not sure about mysql) offer a friendlier delimited-string parsing function, e.g. "split_part()", which would support the more compact:

```
order by to_number(split_part(picture,'_',2))
```